# Unauthorized Access Exception when Creating an instance of SpeechSynthesizer in WP8.1 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I was trying to recreate the simle Text to Speech example used on the MSDN website. However whenever the code came to create the instance of the SpeechSynthesizer class it failed with a Unauthorised Acception error when running on the WP8.1 emulator. I currently do not have an actual device to test on to see if this makes a difference.

My code was simply:

```
    private async void TTS()
    {
        // The media object for controlling and playing audio.
        MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();

        // The object for controlling the speech synthesis engine (voice).
        var synth = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();

        // Generate the audio stream from plain text.
        SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Hello World");

        // Send the stream to the media object.
        mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
        mediaElement.Play();
    }
```

I know there was an issue with the SpeechSynthesizer in Windows 8.1, and I found solutions to this when looking to fix the problem, but found little about the problem with WP8.1 SpeechSynthesizer. Has anybody else came across this problem and found a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add one DeviceCapability in Package.appxmanifest file:

In DeviceCapability Tab, check the ***microphone***, because it will provides access to the microphone’s audio feed, which allows the app to record audio from connected microphones.

Look at this library: [App capability declarations (Windows Runtime apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx#microphone)